# pickling a gridlayout using python and kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, pickle

i have been trying to save the state of my application using python pickle module without success. my application works fine on mobile but whenever i close it, it loses all data. i want this application to be like a table notepad so that i can resume from where i left after closing the app. here is a part of my code to explain the problem.
example.py

```
import pickle


class MyGrid(BoxLayout):
    pass


if os.path.isfile("notepad"):
    load = pickle.load(open("notepad", "rb"))
    print(load)
    textinput = StringProperty(load)
else:
    textinput = StringProperty()


class Goat(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

    def save(self):
        rectangle1 = [self.root.ids.a2.text, self.root.ids.a2.text]
        pickle.dump(rectangle1, open("notepad", "wb"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Goat().run()
```

here is my .kv file

```
<MyGrid>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        bar_width: 10
        GridLayout:
            id:gridlayout
            cols :3
            row_default_height: 90
            height: self.minimum_height
            size: 600, 500
            padding: 5
            pos: 0, -200
            size_hint_y: None
##############################################box1
            Label:
                text : "A"
                background_color: (1, 5, 0, 1)
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id : a1
                multiline : False
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id : a2
                multiline : False
                font_size: 30
            Button:
                text: 'SUBMIT'
                id : submit1
                background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                on_release: app.save()
                font_size: 39
```

when i type on the input field and press submit, a notepad.dat file is formed on the directory and the contents typed on the input field are saved.( i know this by print(load) on my .py file)
my problem is bringing the contents of the dart file on the gui and making them stay there. i dont know how to do that. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the pickled data after the `App` starts so that you can assign the pickled data to the widgets. Like this:

```
class Goat(App):
    def on_start(self):
        if os.path.isfile("notepad"):
            load = pickle.load(open("notepad", "rb"))
            self.root.ids.a1.text = load[0]
            self.root.ids.a2.text = load[1]
```

Comment: thanks for solving my problem.  i was stuck on this problem for like forever. you're heaven sent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73906660/index-error-when-trying-to-pickle-using-python-and-kivy can you help me answer this, they are related