# index error when trying to pickle using python and kivy

Tags: python, kivy, pickle

i am using pickle and i have a small problem that i understand but i don't know how to approach it. i want pickel load to display what's saved and if there's nothing saved it should not throw out an  IndexError: list index out of range. my python and kivy code will help you understand my problem better. below is my .py code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
import os.path
import pickle


class MyGrid(BoxLayout):
    pass


if os.path.isfile("notepad1"):
    load = pickle.load(open("notepad1", "rb"))
    print(load)
    textinput = StringProperty(load)
else:
    textinput = StringProperty()


class Goat(App):
    def on_start(self):
        if os.path.isfile("notepad1"):
            load = pickle.load(open("notepad1", "rb"))
            self.root.ids.a1.text = load[0]
            self.root.ids.a2.text = load[1]
            self.root.ids.a3.text = load[3]


    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

    def save(self):
        rectangle1 = [self.root.ids.a2.text, self.root.ids.a2.text]
        pickle.dump(rectangle1, open("notepad1", "wb"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Goat().run()
```

below is my .kv file

```
<MyGrid>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        bar_width: 10
        GridLayout:
            id:gridlayout
            cols :4
            row_default_height: 90
            height: self.minimum_height
            size: 600, 500
            padding: 5
            pos: 0, -200
            size_hint_y: None
##############################################box1
            Label:
                text : "A"
                background_color: (1, 5, 0, 1)
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id : a1
                multiline : False
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id : a2
                multiline : False
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id : a3
                multiline : False
                font_size: 30
            Button:
                text: 'SUBMIT'
                id : submit1
                background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                on_release: app.save()
                font_size: 39
```

when i run the code it and fill out the three input boxes and press submit, and close the app and then open it again ,everything is okay
but when i run the app fill out only two input boxes and press submit and close the app,and i open it again i get the index error below

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Admin\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-09-30_35.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
['RR', 'RR']
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 30.0.101.1340'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 30.0.101.1340'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\example.py", line 39, in <module>
     Goat().run()
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in _run_prepare
     self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\example.py", line 27, in on_start
     self.root.ids.a3.text = load[3]
 IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i know the error comes from the fact that my .py code is trying to access what is not there in the  notepad file. id like my code to be able to access all that is in the dat file. if there is nothing it should not throw out an error. thanks

Comment: You are pickling a list with 2 elements and trying to access list item `[3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your save function is not saving what I expect you want it to save...

Change it to this....

```
def save(self):
    rectangle1 = [self.root.ids.a1.text, self.root.ids.a2.text, self.root.ids.a3.text]
    pickle.dump(rectangle1, open("notepad1", "wb"))
```

Comment: thank you i now know where the problem was